# Is there a way to view the metadata of SVG or EMF files using open source tools?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I have an image/chart that takes a long time to print - actually, a long time to create the post script file. Years ago I had a tool that allowed me to 'inspect/view' the chart and it visually showed that the chart had some highlighted areas that were "out of bounds" from the top of the image borders. This tool allowed me to edit the metadata and change the value from, say 10,000 to 10 - and that area was back within the image borders.

Apologies if this is vague/unclear.
Basically, I have an EMF file that MSPaint errors with "Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported". It really is an EMF file since the app that creates them saves the charts as EMF.

So, does anyone know of an open source tool that would allow me to edit the metadata of EMF files?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Inkscape allows you to add/modify the XML data as required. Go to Edit->XML Editor to open up the editor and make the changes you need.

I'm not an expert in the area so this couldn't completely off-topic from your original question.  I'm adding this answer based on the 'inkscape' and 'svg' tag in your post.